# Create a testing plan for a huge legacy application

Tags: manual-testing

I have been tasked with creating test scripts for each and every menu item of an application with 600+ menu items. I was wondering if there is a faster way to do this than going through every single menu item and creating a test script for it?

Comment: It is to broad question, since the answer depends on how those items organized, if they correlate, if the set is dependent on some conditions, etc.

Comment: Tools such as Hexawise (https://www.hexawise.com/features) might come into rescue here.  If those menu options are inter-related, then you will also be able to optimise the coverage.   This one comes with a cost attached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

600+ Menu items?  I don't envy that task!

If this is a legacy application and is already in Production use, maybe you could look at testing 'areas' instead of single menu options.

I don't know the business area or anything about your app, but my first thoughts in response to your question would be to understand the main uses of the system.  I'd be looking for a dozen of these and then write some tests to test each main use.  I'd hope each of these tests touches upon several menu options.

With a small set of tests, I'd then put together a matrix.  Menu options on one axis and the names of the tests on other axis.  That way you can map which options are covered by which tests, which options need tests, etc.

Hopefully with this approach, you might have less individual scripts to run.